# Formula for counting pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on this problem :Suppose $i=1,2...n, j=1,2...n, N<n$, how many pairs are there for $|i-j|>N$?
I think the answer should be $(n-N)*(n-N-1)$, but the answer for my exercise shows that this value to be $(n-N)^2$ I get my answer by enumeration and find the law. Is the answer wrong or my thought has something incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is correct, assuming that you’re counting **ordered** pairs: a glance at the appropriate picture shows that it’s $2\sum_{k=1}^{n-N-1}k=(n-N)(n-N-1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You’re welcome!